# Cannot turn gas valve. It is stuck

Tags: natural-gas

I need to turn off the gas to to the house to do a repair of an appliance without its own valve. It seems stuck as I cannot turn it with a crescent wrench.

Answer (score 2):

After another attempt, I succeeded. I reoriented the crescent wrench in the opposite direction (concave side away from me) and pulled towards me. I believe this gave me more leverage is it was significantly easier to turn.

Other ideas that I ended up not trying but may help as well:

1. Getting an extra large crescent wrench (expensive).
2. Getting a tool with linear slot that fits over the valve's knob which appears to be created for opening valves.
3. (Rob's suggestion) As the valve is located outdoors, there was a bit of rust or dirt that can add friction to the valve. Using PB Blaster or Liquid Wrench can help loosen things up. (NB: please check if this is safe)

Comment: you don't mention the state of the valve but if it's outside and been sitting a long time, it might be rusty. Next time a penetrating oil like PB Blaster or Liquid Wrench might help.

Comment: @RobElliott It is outdoors and looks slightly rusted. That may have helped indeed.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference: get a piece of pipe large enough to slip over the handle of the wrench, as long as will fit in your space, to increase the leverage. We call them "persuaders".